# Reverse bits of unit32 in go

Tags: go

I want to flip the binary number 1000 to 0001. <s>The bits.reverse function doesn't seem to work.</s>

The problem is I am getting bits from a GPIO. Either 4bits or 26bits, the problem is they are in the wrong direction (1 = 1000, 2=0100 ..., also the 26bit).

Can anyone help me?

Here is my example code:

```golang
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "math/bits"
)

func main() {
    var x uint32 = 0b1000
    fmt.Printf("%04b\n", x)
    fmt.Printf("%04b\n", bits.Reverse32(x))
}
```

Comment: Try printing it with `%032b`, that should give you a good idea why.

Comment: `bits.Reverse32()` does reverse the bits of a 32-bit number. What do you want to do? Do you want to reverse a 4-bit number? Please clarify your question.

Comment: I also just realized that I asked the question badly. Second, the function works as it should. I have changed the question

Comment: I known the answer, but cannot write an answer, since the question is closed. Can anyone re-open it, so I can post it, which might benefit others at later time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`bits.Reverse32()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/bits/#example_Reverse32) to reverse the bits of a 32-bit number, but since your "useful" bits are less than 32, you have to shift right the result with the number of "useless" bits.

For example if you have 4 useful bits, after reversing those 4 bits will go to the highest 4 bits, so shift right by `32-4 = 28`.

A function capturing this logic:

```
func reverse(x uint32, size uint32) uint32 {
    return bits.Reverse32(x) >> (32 - size)
}
```

Example testing it:

```
x := uint32(0b1000)
fmt.Printf("x:   %04b\n", x)
fmt.Printf("rev: %04b\n", reverse(x, 4))

x = uint32(0x3000010)
fmt.Printf("x:   %026b\n", x)
fmt.Printf("rev: %026b\n", reverse(x, 26))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/_hhJ65-hX3s)):

```
x:   1000
rev: 0001
x:   11000000000000000000010000
rev: 00001000000000000000000011
```

Answer (score -1):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/bits"
)

func main() {
    var x uint32 = 0b1000
    fmt.Printf("%032b\n", x)
    fmt.Printf("%032b\n", bits.Reverse32(x))
}

Input:  00000000000000000000000000001000
Output: 00010000000000000000000000000000
```

This should work. Reference: https://golang.org/pkg/math/bits/#Reverse32

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, it just shows why he is getting that result.